# WPF Datagrid read a cell value

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am trying to find out how to read the value of my WPF datagrid cells.

something along the lines of

```
String myString = myDataGrid.Cells[1][2].ToString();
```

the datagrid has been created in XAML and i have populated the datagrid with row data by using

```
reportGrid.Items.Add(new cbResultRow() { ... });
```

now I want to go back and read cell values in my datagrid.

I have seen some examples of reading data from a selected row or cell, by I don't have any selection (the user doesnt interact with the datagrid).

i have also seen code like

```
foreach(DataGridRow myrow in myDataGrid.Rows)
```

however the compiler says Rows is not a member of datagrid.

I have searched for several hours to try to find out how to do what I would have thought was a very simple thing!

please help,

Thanks,
will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WPF datagrid was built to bind to something like a DataTable. The majority of the time, you will modify the DataTable, and the Rows/Columns within the DataTable that is bound to the DataGrid.

The DataGrid itself is the Visual Element for the DataTable. [Here is a pretty good tutorial on how to do this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-the-wpf-toolkit-datagrid). To modify data within a loop would look something like this.

```
foreach(DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
{
    row["ColumnTitle"] = 1;
}
```

This would simply make all the values in Column "ColumnTitle" equal to 1. To access a single cell it would look something like this.

```
myTable.Rows[0][0] = 1;
```

This would set the first cell in your DataTable to 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had already done it similar the way you suggested by first creating a List (since there is no datatable) and binding the datagrid to the list, but I really wanted to know if there is a way to access cell data directly from the datagrid.

Comment: @dontpanic there is not. And in the future, you'll find that a List does not work near as well as a DataTable. I would even prefer an ObservableCollection over a List.

Answer (score 2):

This might help someone else.

```
foreach (DataRowView row in dgLista.SelectedItems)
{
    string text = row.Row.ItemArray[index].ToString();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Nice idea. Just a word of caution: This will work only in the most basic situations, where your data source is a `DataView` and your `DataGrid` is showing all the columns of the data source in the same order, i.e. 1 to 1 mapping is used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a summary of the solution.

Winform

Type: System.windows.Forms.DataGridView

```
// C#
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  //"Column1" = column name in DataGridView
  string text = row.Cells["Column1"].value.ToString();
}
```

WPF equivalent

Type: DataGrid

```
// C#
foreach (DataRowView row in dataGrid.Items)
{
  string text = row.Row.ItemArray[index].ToString();
}
```