# Read each cell values in WPF gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I have a datagridview in wpf called `datagrid1`. I need to read value in each cells in datagrid. I know how to do it in windows form

```
string result = datagrid1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

How do this in WPF?

Comment: Are you using `MVVM` pattern in your development? if not you can still access `datagrid1` in your cs file.

Comment: Please specify why you want to read cell values? Best practice is to use MVVM and you wont come across such kind situations.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this in WPF, however this [tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21202.wpf-programmatically-selecting-and-focusing-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid.aspx) can be of use to you.

Edit:

First of all I totally agree with the comment Nitin Joshi mentioned above. 
Second, According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368443/1648849) The WPF datagrid was built to bind to something like a DataTable. The majority of the time, you will modify the `DataTable`, and the Rows/Columns within the `DataTable` that is bound to the `DataGrid`, not the `DataGrid` it self so you don't need to use something like this `datagrid1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value`. But if you still insist on getting the value that way, here is a solution :

**Second EDIT:**
Since you asked only for a way to read call value, I'll make my answer shorter but also a little more concrete:
GetCellValue method returns a string value representing cell content of a given `DataGrid` by column/row indices:

*I wrote this method assuming column types are either `TextBox`, `TextBlock` or `ComboBox`. Other Types could be handled the same way.*

```
    public string GetCellValue(DataGrid datagrid, int row, int column)
    {
        var cellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(
            datagrid.Items[row], dataGrid.Columns[column]);

        DataGridCell cell = null;
        var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
        if (cellContent != null)
            cell = (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;

        if (cell == null) return string.Empty;

        // if DataGridTextColumn / DataGridComboBoxColumn is used 
        // or AutoGeneratedColumns is True
        if (cell.Content is TextBlock)
            return ((TextBlock)cell.Content).Text;
        else if (cell.Content is ComboBox)
            return ((ComboBox)cell.Content).Text;

        // if DataGridTemplateColumn is used 
        // assuming cells are either TextBox, TextBlock or ComboBox. Other Types could be handled the same way.
        else
        {
            var txtPresenter = FindVisualChild<TextBox>((ContentPresenter)cell.Content);
            if (txtPresenter != null) return txtPresenter.Text;
            var txbPresenter = FindVisualChild<TextBlock>((ContentPresenter)cell.Content);
            if (txbPresenter != null) return txbPresenter.Text;
            var cmbPresenter = FindVisualChild<ComboBox>((ContentPresenter)cell.Content);
            if (cmbPresenter != null) return cmbPresenter.Text;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
                return (T)child;
            else
            {
                T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then calling `string result = GetCellValue(dataGrid, 2, 1);` (e.g. from a Button click event), will return the value of dataGrid[2,1].

*Note:

1. The `SelectionUnit` of the `DataGrid` must be set to `Cell`.
2. The `DataGrid`must fully generated otherwise `ItemContainerGenerator` returns null.
3. GetCellValue method works for a few `UIElements` considered to be more common to be used as `DataGridColumn` Types.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But i have a another problem with above code. that is  inside the method "SelectCellByIndex"  condition "if (cell.Content is TextBlock)" return false then return result is null (empty). datagrid is fully generated but why return empty value as cell value.

Comment: I wrote that block of code assuming each cell in your datagrid is a TextBlock. What is the type of cell.content? if its not a TextBlock, then try to find out the type, and change that part of your code to return the string value representing  cell value.