# How to get value of the cell in a specific row in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

im new to wpf. I wanted to know how am i going to get cell value on specific row.

I can do this is winform's datagridview. But i dont know how to do this in wpf's datagrid..below is the code of my winform's datagridview:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    text = "P" + String.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value).ToString("0.00"));

    graphic.DrawString(text, font7Reg, new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black), new RectangleF(x, y, width, height), drawFormatRight);
}
```

how am i going to translate this code to datagrid of wpf:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value
```

Comment: Why don't you take it from your model to which grid is bound? Instead of doing this mumbo-jumbo that was probably wrong approach in winforms also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Datagrid read a cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368302/wpf-datagrid-read-a-cell-value)

Comment: Start with [tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/). While it *may* be possible to keep winforms approach you better study WPF.

Comment: Doubt it is winforms approach, I would before call it dont-think-just-make-it-work.

Comment: You can [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45956589/6611487) which would get you, what u desire

Comment: @Dusan my bad.. There was a mistake in my sample code. I edited it.. and btw, that sample code was just 1 column of many columns i have in my datagridview (winform app) to atleast give a better understanding.. do you know how to do it in wpf app?

Comment: "do you know how to do it in wpf app"? Try to read the answers.

Comment: none of the answers solve my problem. I already have a datagrid and have two columns (description and price). It is being populated by the service or item that a customer wants. it can have massive rows, thats why im using for loop to populate my receipt printing function.  now what i want is i wanted to programmatically get each cell value of each row of the said datagrid..

Comment: That's exactly what the code in my answer does...what is the name of your class with the descrpition and price properties? Show how you populate the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Data binding technique is normally used in the WPF application.

STEP 1
Create class and define the properties inside it. (creation of model)

```
public class Student : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    string _address;
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { _address = value; OnPropertyChanged("Address"); }
    }

    int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; OnPropertyChanged("Age"); }
    }
}



public abstract class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

NotifyPropertyChanged class notigy the object when it is triggered

STEP 2
Create another class for ViewModel where your Business logic should go
Create a list of model property(which will be used in the view binding)

```
public class MyContext : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<Student> _students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get { return _students; }
        set { _students = value; OnPropertyChanged("Students"); }
    }

    Student _selectedStudent = new Student();
    public Student SelectedStudent
    {
        get { return _selectedStudent; }
        set { _selectedStudent = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedStudent"); }
    }
}
```

STEP 3
bind your logic to the view ()

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
      public MainWindow()
     {
          InitializeComponent();

        MyContext myContext = new MyContext();
        myContext.Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>
        {
            new Student{ Name="A", Address="Address1", Age=10},
            new Student{ Name="B", Address="Address2", Age=12},
            new Student{ Name="C", Address="Address3", Age=11},
            new Student{ Name="D", Address="Address4", Age=18},
            new Student{ Name="E", Address="Address5", Age=13},
            new Student{ Name="F", Address="Address6", Age=15},
            new Student{ Name="G", Address="Address7", Age=16},
        };

        this.DataContext = myContext;
    }
}
```

STEP 4
finally in your XAML page add a DataGrid and Bind ItemsSource to it as defined named in the ViewModel

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Students,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Window>
```

In the above code i showed how to bind a list of values to WPF DataGrid and select single value from it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have set or bound the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to an `IEnumerable<T>`, you could cast each object in the `Items` collection to `T` and then access any of its properties, e.g.:

```
foreach(var item in salesGrid.Items.OfType<YourType>())
{
    string text = item.YourProperty.ToString();
}
```

Or you could iterate through the `ItemsSource` collection directly.