# Return Cell 0 as a string from the selected Row in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datarowview

I want to return the value of cell 0 from a row I double clicked on in a **DataGrid**. So far I can return the values of cell 0 from all rows, but I only want the cell 0 value of the row I double clicked on.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368302/wpf-datagrid-read-a-cell-value) which I iterate through in my example code.

```
private void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataRowView row in dataGrid.Items)
    {
        string text = row.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: clicked item should get selected. use `dataGrid.SelectedItem as DataRowView` (and do a `null`-check!)

Comment: @ASh Both your answer and waka's answer works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SelectedItems` instead of `Items`

```
foreach (DataRowView row in dataGrid.SelectedItems)
{
    string text = row.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine(text);
}
```